# Как получить результат от запущенного активити?

Tags: android

Если я запущу через `startActivity` скайп из своего приложения, то как мне в `service` получить результат о том что скайп свернулся или закрылся?

Comment: можно через Intent-ы попробовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При использовании **startActivity** активити скайпа добавится в ваш Task и при сворачивании или закрытии скайпа из back-stack вылезет в активность ваша активити, т.е. можно отслеживать OnResume вашего Activity, из которого вы вызвали **startActivity** скайпа, а при ситуации закрытия скайпа в OnResume отловить этот момент и забиндить сервис.

Comment: Знаю про Back. Но ты забываешь про кнопку меню. И как быть в таком случае?))) Меню перехватить нельзя, а значит такой способ нельзя использовать. Нужно именно перехватить момент когда скайп выключается или сворачивается.

Comment: Насколько я знаю напрямую следить за чочтоянием возможности нету. Пока более путного решения точно не смогу предложить. Нужно подумать

Comment: Кстати ты тут забываешь одну вещь. Данный твой метод работает тольк при установке, а я писал же вверху что нужно отлавить ЗАПУСК.

Comment: Когда вы выполняете startActivity() для запуска скайпа, вот он ваш момент отлавливания запуска